# Rails 3 autocomplete crowdint plugin jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, plugins, autocomplete

I wanted to set up textbox with autocomplete feature using crowdint plugin.
So I made everything like in documentation.

There is no error but text field works like regular text box.

I did include javascript for plugin

I did instal jquery-rails also

When i type link responsible for autocomplte action:

    http://localhost:3000/general_items/autocomplete_items_type_name?term=b

there appears found record. 

    [{"id":1,"label":"book","value":"book"}]

It means that autocomplete works but when i'm typing a word in text box nothing happens
text box:

I checked and my browser, **it doesn't send any request to server** during typing a word...

any suggestions?

## edit

so everything what i've done to set it up:

-----------------------plugin installation -------------------------

Installing

sudo gem install rails3-jquery-autocomplete

```
gem install jquery-rails
```

Include the gem on Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
```

Install it

```
bundle install
```

Run the generator

```
rails generate autocomplete
```

And include autocomplete-rails.js on my layouts

```
javascript_include_tag "autocomplete-rails.js"
```

----------------models-----------------------------

```
class GeneralItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :theuser , :foreign_key => "user_id"
  belongs_to :items_type , :foreign_key => "type_id"  
  #more code there...

end


class ItemsType < ActiveRecord::Base 

has_many :theitems 
has_many :general_items

accepts_nested_attributes_for :general_items, :allow_destroy => true


end
```

table items_type has columns: id, name, created_at, modified_at

-------------controllers---------------------------

```
class GeneralItemsController < ApplicationController
  autocomplete :items_type, :name

more code there...
```

-------------views----------------------------

layoute file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Library</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
  <%=  javascript_include_tag "autocomplete-rails.js" %>

  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>

_form.html.erb:

<%= form_for(@general_item) do |f| %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :user_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :user_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
   <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :type %><br />
    <%= f.autocomplete_field :descr_english, autocomplete_items_type_name_general_items_path %>

  </div>

more code there...
```

as i wrote it seems that plugin is working but application doesn't send querys dynamicly during typing leters in autocomplete_field...

Comment: Please share your controller code

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're missing the form configuration or your autocomplete.js file is actually missing, if you didn't use the generator from the gem to install it.

Do you have lines like this in your form?

```
form_for @product do |f|
  f.autocomplete_field :brand_name, autocomplete_brand_name_products_path
end
```

Comment: i have them as: 


<%= form_for(@general_item) do |f| %>
#more code here...

<%= f.autocomplete_field :descr_english, autocomplete_items_type_name_general_items_path %>

autocomplete.js is here as:
autocomplete-rails.js

can i use this generator to generate the form itself?